# Как можно вывести на страницу изображение с описанием изображения из БД

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

у меня есть код для вывода описания из БД на страницу под фото, но выводит одно и тоже описание под каждое фото. попробовал через ид, но у меня постоянно выдает ошибку и не получается вывести. подскажите, как можно этот код подредактировать или что использовать лучше?

```
$dbh = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "ngg");

 if(mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   exit("Ошибка подключения к базе данных MySQL: Сервер база данных не доступен!<br>
   Проверте параметры подключения к базе данных.");
 }

 $text = "SELECT description from binary_data";
 $result = $dbh->query($text);
 if(!$result) exit("Ошибка выполнения SQL запроса!");

 $row = $result->fetch_array();
```

А вывожу на странице вот так

```
<?php echo $row['description']; ?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT description from binary_data"` может нужно  добавить `WHERE id = ?` или что там у вас, чтоб точно отфильтровать нужное?

Comment: пробовал добавить `WHERE id=".$_GET['id];` но в таком случае он вообще не выводит описание, а сразу выдает Ошибку выполнения SQL запроса. а конкретный id задавать не вариант

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому то будет полезно решение которое я нашел для этого случая.

```
<?php
                             $dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ngg");

                             if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                             {
                               exit("Ошибка подключения к базе данных MySQL: Сервер база данных не доступен!<br>
                               Проверте параметры подключения к базе данных.");
                             }

                             $text = "SELECT * FROM binary_data";
                             $result = $dbh->query($text);
                             if(!$result) exit("Ошибка выполнения SQL запроса!");

                            if($result){
                                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                                for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j){
                                    $row = $result->fetch_array();
                                    $description = $row['description'];
                                        echo "<li>";
                                        echo "<a href='#'>";
                                        for ($i = 0; $i < 1; ++$i) echo "<img src='getdata.php?id=$j' data-large='getdata.php?id=$j' alt='image[$j]' data-description='$description'/>";
                                        echo "</a>";
                                        echo "</li>";
                                }
                            } ?>
```

так же код со страницы getdata.php

```
<?php

 if(!preg_match("|^[\d]*$|",$_GET['id'])) exit();

 // подключение к базе данных
 // (возможно, вам придется настроить имя хоста, имя пользователя и пароль)
 $dbh = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ngg");

 if(mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   exit("Ошибка подключения к базе данных MySQL: Сервер база данных не доступен!<br>
   Проверте параметры подключения к базе данных.");
 }

 $query = "SELECT bin_data,filetype from binary_data WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
 $result = $dbh->query($query);

 if(!$result) exit("Ошибка выполнения SQL запроса!");

 $row = $result->fetch_array();

 Header( "Content-type: ".$row['filetype']."");
 echo $row['bin_data'];

 ?>
```